# How to make a hotkey for a series of keyboard commands?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I would like to be able to do

```
Ctrl + S, Alt + Tab and F5
```

while only pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Install the `xautomation`
   package (`sudo apt-get install xautomation`).  This provides the command [`xte`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte) which is used for simulating keyboard events.
2. Open up *System ➜ Preferences ➜ Keyboard Shortcuts*.
3. Click on *Add* and use the following code for the *Command*,

   ```
   xte "keydown Control_L" "key s" "keyup Control_L" "keydown Alt_L" "key Tab" "keyup Alt_L" "key F5"
   ```

   Use whatever you want for the *Name* and then click *Apply*.

   [image]
4. Now click the right side of the new shortcut entry (where it says *Disabled* ) and hit

   <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

   [image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for giving me an idea for the name of the shortcut. I couldn't figure out how to call it.